# div appear smoothly using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my div should appears smoothly after a while, i think it needs a transition script code, this is my script that shows the div after 800 pixels scrolled down.

```
          $(document).scroll(function() {
          var y = $(this).scrollTop();
          if (y > 700) {
          $('.menu').fadeIn();
          } else {
          $('.menu').fadeOut();
          }
          });
```

I don't know how to put transition in this code, sorry i don't know javascript at all

Comment: use this `$('.menu').fadeIn(1000);`

Comment: where should i put it? i open a new script tag but it doesn't work

Comment: check this out https://jsfiddle.net/hkxcsmk4/

Comment: it works well but it makes a new problem, my menu doesn't work anymore(i mean it doesn't open the menu content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a better experience use CSS transitions and not jQuery animations. The way to do it is to use your scroll function to add / remove classes from your menu element and than use css to create the fade in effect.

For example:

**CSS**

```
.menu {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .4s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-out;
}

.menu.show {
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 700) {
        $('.menu').addClass("show");
    } else {
        $('.menu').removeClass("show);
    }
});
```